# shared partial - record not being saved - param is missing or the value is empty - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, multipartform-data

I can't save a new record.  The data / input is being submitted by a `form_for` - a shared partial - which is displayed in a view rendered by the `users_controller`

In the `users_controller.rb`, the view page `user_home.html.erb`:

```
def user_home
  if user_signed_in?
    @user = current_user
    @cpe_event = CpeEvent.new
  end
end
```

(Removing `@cpe_event = CpeEvent.new` causes a `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` error in the view.)

In my `cpe_events_controller.rb` I have a #create action:

```
def create
  @cpe_event = CpeEvent.new
  @user = current_user     
  @cpe_event = current_user.cpe_events.build(cpe_event_params)
  ...
```

The data is submitted by a form - a shared partial:

```
<%= form_for @cpe_event, url: cpe_events_path, method: :post, 
html: { multipart: true }, class: 'form-inline form_for form_for_content' do |f| %>
```

I am getting this error on the `@cpe_event = current_user.cpe_events.build(cpe_event_params)` line:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: cpe_event
```

The permitted params code is:

```
def cpe_event_params
  params.require(:cpe_event).permit(....
```

If I place `raise params.inspect` after `def create`, I get a hash of the params submitted:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"u1...1g==", "sponsor_name"=>"WI - TEST",
"class_date"=>"2014-01-01", "title"=>"How Account", "commit"=>"Submit",
"controller"=>"cpe_events", "action"=>"create"}
```

If I remove `(cpe_event_params)` from the line `@cpe_event = current_user.cpe_events.build(cpe_event_params)` and inspect the output, I get a record with nil values - except for the user_id:

```
#<CpeEvent id: nil, course_id: nil, recruiter_id: nil, sponsor_id: nil, user_id: 2,
created_at: nil, updated_at: nil,....
```

So I seem to be saving a record / `CpeEvent` but with no data.

Adding back the `(cpe_event_params)` gives me:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: cpe_event
```

The values being submitted - :sponsor_name, :class_date, and :title - should be saved as strings in the database.

How do I resolve this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think, in the below parameters that submitted by your form, there is no parameter called 'cpe_event', that is why it is throwing error while requiring 'cpe_event' parameter using below method. Make sure that 'cpe_event' parameter is submitted by your form.

```
params.require(:cpe_event).permit(....
```

> {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"u1...1g==", "sponsor_name"=>"WI
>   TEST", "class_date"=>"2014-01-01", "title"=>"How Account",
>   "commit"=>"Submit", "controller"=>"cpe_events", "action"=>"create"}

Comment: You're correct; however, that doesn't resolve the issue.  I re-posted the question (#30464733) based upon your input.  I think the issue is the `f.select` fields rather than `f.text_field`  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you send me the view code of your form? because above parameters are not in the format, in which it should be, when a form is submitted. It should be in format like `{  "utf" =>  ......., "cpe_event" => { form parameters comes here }, "commit" => "Submit", "controller" => "cpe_events", "action" => "create"}`